# Incorrect usage of a for loop in strstr() in C

Tags: c, string, loops, strstr

I am trying to learn string handling in C. I wrote out a program, which stores some music tracks, and helps the user to check if the song he/she has in mind, exists in the tracks stored. This is done by asking the user to enter a string of characters. The program then uses the strstr() function to check if the word/text entered matches with any word/text on any track, and if so, it displays the track number and name.

The code which I have written functions properly on the outset. But there's a big flaw, and it is due to incorrect usage of the for loop. I'll show the program and two pieces of output first-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

//Define tracks array
char tracks[][80]={     //[][80] is a 2D array- for storing tracks and the size of each track, which is 80 at max
"I left my heart in Harvard med school",
"Newark, Newark- a wonderful town",
"Dancing with a dork",
"From here to maternity",
"The girl from Iwo Jima",
};

//Define function to search for text in tracks array

void findTrack(char search_for[])
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
       if(strstr(tracks[i], search_for))    
       {
          printf("\n Match found\n");       
          printf("\n Track[%i]: %s\n", i, tracks[i]);
          break;
       }
       else
           printf("\n No matching tracks found!");
       }
}

int main()
{
   char search_for[80];
   printf("\n Enter the text to search:\n");
   scanf("%79s", search_for);
   findTrack(search_for);
   return 0;
}
```

1st Output-

```
 Enter the text to search:
Harvard

 Match found

 Track[0]: I left my heart in Harvard med school
```

As you can see, this output is correct. The word `Harvard` was present in the first track I stored in the `tracks` array. This was found in the first iteration of the `for loop` inside the `findTrack` function, hence the correct output.

However, if I run the program again, and this time I give the text to search as `town`, the resulting output is -

2nd Output-

```
Enter the text to search:
town

 No matching tracks found!
 Match found

 Track[1]: Newark, Newark- a wonderful town
```

This happened because on the first iteration of the `for` loop ie: `tracks[0]`, the `strstr` did not find any match, so it printed the statement in the `else` part of the loop. When the loop completed iteration 1, for `tracks[1]`, a match was found in `town`, and hence it printed the `if` part of the loop.

Similarly, if I run the program again and give `Jima` as the text to search, the output is-

```
 Enter the text to search:
Jima

 No matching tracks found!
 No matching tracks found!
 No matching tracks found!
 No matching tracks found!
 Match found

 Track[4]: The girl from Iwo Jima
```

I think the flaw is due to the incorrect for loop. But I'm not sure how to do it right using a for loop. Any suggestions on correcting this would be highly appreciated.
Thank You!

**EDIT**

In my code, I'm using a `for` loop with `i<5`because I know that there are `5 tracks` stored in my program. However, a better way to code would be to run a loop irrespective of/in cases when the number of tracks is not known. This could happen in a scenario when my number of tracks change, so it would be inefficient to keep changing the for loop each time. Any suggestions on how to implement this change?

Comment: you could declare the string array as `char *tracks[] = {"xxx","yyy",..., NULL}` then you do not need to know how many string there are since you can loop until you find NULL. `for (i = 0; tracks[i] != NULL; ++i)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only want to print `Not found` after checking the entire array `tracks` for match. So you could use a flag and check it after the loop:

```
void findTrack(char search_for[])
{
  int i;
  int found = 0;
  for(i=0;i<5;i++)
  {
    if(strstr(tracks[i], search_for))   
    {
    found = 1;
    printf("\n Match found\n");     
    printf("\n Track[%i]: %s\n", i, tracks[i]);
    break;
    }
  }
  if (!found)     printf("\n No matching tracks found!");
}
```

Comment: Since C99, C actually has a `bool` type, and `true` and `false` literals. All you need to do is `#include <stdbool.h>` to step out of the "everything is an `int`" ages.

Comment: There are plenty of systems still using C89.

Comment: @BlueMoon Thank You! The usage of flag is very helpful.

Comment: @BlueMoon, plenty? Just one kind, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (strstr(tracks[i], searchfor) {
        printf("\nMatch found\n);
        printf("Track[%n]: %s", i, tracks[i]);
        return;
    }
}
printf("\nNo matching tracks found!");
```

Answer (score 0):

to adapt to a variable type you can use a define

```
#define TRACKS 5
```

right after the includes... whenever you want to change the amount no another value you just have to change that 5 to the new value.

```
 void findTrack(char search_for[])
 {
    int i;
    int found = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < TRACKS; i++)
    {
       if(strstr(tracks[i], search_for))   
       {
           found = 1;
           printf("\n Match found\n");     
           printf("\n Track[%i]: %s\n", i, tracks[i]);     
           //break;
       }
    }

    if (!found)     printf("\n No matching tracks found!");
  }
```

I've commented the break because that depends on what you want to do... If you want to find **just the first** track that has that word in it you should let the break but if you want to find  **all**  matches, then you shouldn't break after findind the first one.